# What's the most efficient / fast way to display website within another website?

Tags: ajax, iframe, frame

I am developing my portfolio website and I thought that it would be nice to show websites I've created within my portfolio website.

So say I will have header with navigation of my portfolio website and beneath it a  or  with another website from my portfolio list.

I mentioned  and  as I've heard that they can do such job, but I have no idea of how to use them.

So could anyone please suggest the way that is efficient, browser friendly, wouldn't take a lot of my server resources to display different websites (and will do the job).

**Additionally:** the way that I was planning to do this is by having links to different websites like http://webpage.com/portfolio.php?url=**http://anotherWebpage.com** so when user clicks it the website shown in the  (or something else) would be http://anotherWebpage.com . Also if possible could someone suggest "AJAX" method that will not require page refresh and will show different webpage in  (or something else ;D ) instantly after user clicks on different links

Thank You )))

Comment: yeh I know it could be used for that, but i don't know how to use it correctly, I made a research with google, but I don't really think I understood it well, so I asked here - How to correctly use iframe in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript and iframe

```
<a href="http://yourpage.com" onclick="document.getElementById('iframe').src=this.href;return false">My page</a>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Alrigh't I see, could you please explain this bit - onclick="document.getElementById('iframe').src=this.href;return false

Comment: @IlyaKnaup: it changes src of that iframe on second line to current url of that `<a>` tag

Comment: cool )) I tried it out. I do have an issue though: when I change url's they look something like http://portfolio-website.com/portfplio.php?url=http://another-website.com and this is url that goes in iframe, but I only need http://another-website.com bit to go there. is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup: why do they look like this?

Comment: well the first bit http://portfolio-website.com/portfolio.php is a page of my website where I have iframe. ?url=http://another-website.com this bit is what i collect with php get["url"] and this I want to display in iframe, this bit changes each time user clicks different link.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup: question is, why?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the iframe is your best bet.

You would want to have a page with your toolbar and all your navigational elements and then an iframe that can change its source when you click a link.

You've probably heard that iframes don't always play nice with every browser but there are some ways you can eliminate the problems that come up.

Sometimes they really are the best way to do things!

Check out some tips [here](http://blog.futtta.be/2010/03/03/5-tips-to-tackle-the-problem-with-iframes/) and [here](http://www.iframehtml.com/)